# Java loop missing elements in given array

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I have simple `for` loop that iterates through an `ArrayList` of objects. Each time it checks if adding the current object will increase the total of the list x above a capacity. If the capaticy is not reached or exceeded it adds the object to list x, if otherwise, it adds list x to another list y of x's, clears list x, and then adds the current object.

```
List<Customer> route = new ArrayList<Customer>();

for(Polar s:polars) {
    if((requirment(route) + s.getCustomer().c) <= prob.depot.c) {
        route.add(s.getCustomer());
    } else {
        soln.add(route);
        route.clear();
        route.add(s.getCustomer());
    }
}
```

Now I have printed the list of objects so as to verify that is in the correct order which it is, but performing this loop outputs only one list, and seems to miss the first several items in the list of objects. Its a simple loop but I can't for the life of me work out what is wrong.

Any help is appreciated!

For completion here is `requirment()`:

```
public int requirment(List<Customer> route) {
    int r = 0;
    if(route.isEmpty() == true) return 0;
    for(Customer cust : route) {
        r = r + cust.c;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: the debugger is your only hope here I think

Comment: This code doesn't compile it's `isEmpty()` with patenthesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is definition of soln :

```
List<List<Customer>> soln = new ArrayList<List<Customer>>();
```

In Java, non-primitive types have stored data in memory and variables have reference to them. Therefore each item in your list have reference to one route somewhere in memory.

When you do this

```
        soln.add(route);
        route.clear();
```

You add the reference of some route into soln and then you call clear method on the same entity you have stored in soln. The last list is not wiped, because for-cycle ends before clear method is called.

---

This is how you fix that :

```
        soln.add(route);
        route = new ArrayList<Customer>();
```

It means that reference of route is saved in soln and then on the second line, to variable route you store new instance (which does not call clear method on route you want to store instead)

Comment: this seems to sort the issue of the first objects being missed, but no only outputs the very first list... and once the capacity is reached no other lists are added to soln

Comment: @JackMoulson - just replace that code and watch the miracle :).

Comment: i changed `route.clear()` to `route = new ArrayList<Customer>();` soln only ends up containing one list, or did i missunderstand you :P

Comment: @JackMoulson - that means only once was your limit exceeded, or it was not even fired with data you have. I do not know your data and rest of code, but what I show you was really incorrect.

Comment: a yes i have just realised that the last objects do not exceed capcity! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

If soln is a `List<Customer>` object, then you only want to copy to content of route. Just use

```
soln.addAll(route);
```

instead of

```
soln.add(route);
```

Comment: Sorry, this cant even compile, if that was true.